# Integrating SAP with PHP backend

Tags: php, mysql, sap-basis

I have to get data from one company which uses SAP for product management and so on. I should just retrieve data once in a day and refresh my local mysql db. I am php developer, so I know about SAP only in general. What should I say to my partner company about how we should organize data retrieving? And is my logic (retrieve data once in a day and refresh my local mysql db) right? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract data from a SAP ABAP system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107008/how-to-extract-data-from-a-sap-abap-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way to communicate with a SAP system from PHP . The two easiest are web services and RFC (remote function call. There is a library to encapsulate the second one in php [here](http://saprfc.sourceforge.net/).

You should first discuss with your partner company (i suppose they are the one managing the SAP part of the job, or the SAP system) what way they prefer or autorise. You should also check what API they already possess (i'm using API loosely here : web service or set of RFC-enabled functions), or what they are willing to develop for your project, ie how they will allow you to access the data.

As for the logic, it really depends on your needs, so i can not judge that. what are you going to do with the data ? calculs ? access for n external application, in which case why don't you call directly SAP (there may be some good reason)